# preg_match regex syntax

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Tried different regex generators with no luck.

I have this string that i put in preg_match:

```
$search_string = "/^:([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)[@!~a-zA-Z0-9@\.\-]+\s*([A-Z]+)\s*[:]*([\#a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)*\s*[:]*([!\#\-\.A-Za-z0-9 ]+)*/";
```

It's basically for usernames. Sadly, when username has underscore in it. For example iam_coolguy wouldn't work.

How to add underscore to this search string?
I can't seem to figure out how regex works.

It's not a duplicate, scrolled past all preg_match threads.

*/[a-z]/i* seems easy and understandable for me, but my string is too advanced for my knowledge.

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with `[a-z_]+` to match usernames having `_` ? Why such a long regex ?

Comment: Why in the world are you limiting usernames?

Comment: Since you haven't shown us samples of inputs, we can't help you. "username" is essentially useless information. **ANYTHING** could be a username, meaning `/.*/` would be a valid regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to grab somthing between //'s

I would just use this regex `\/(.*)\/`

but as the others have said, you havent given any limitations on what the username can and can't have in it.

If you need more, say something and I will adjust my answer.